# GCLK and GEN pins

Tags: gpio

I'm using Raspberry pi 2, in that there are:  one GPIO_GCLK pin, seven GPIO_GEN pins

I don't no for what purpose these pins are used for, do they have any special purpose?
can anyone explain it in detail?

Comment: Have you even attempted to google your question?

Comment: @Jacobm001 This is the first result on google when I searched for the same question.

Answer (score 4):

`GPIO_GCLK` is the GPIO General Purpose Clock (GPCLK in the datasheet linked). You can set it to generate a square wave up to 125 MHz at 1.2 V, according to the [BCM2835 ARM Peripherals](http://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bcm2835/BCM2835-ARM-Peripherals.pdf) datasheet page 103 and page 106.

GEN pins are just regular GPIO pins from the user's perspective. Nothing special.

Useful link: http://elinux.org/RPi_BCM2835_GPIOs